# Can a <script> have two "types" at the same time?

Tags: html, types, modular, script-tag

I have the following problem, I want a function to be executed when I click a button, for which I have the following code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="printResult()">Calcular</button>
```

And I reference the script like this:

```
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

Now, it happens that when I hit the button I get the error "printResult is not defined". I could solve this by changing the type of the script to "text / javascript". However, the file is modular and I need it to be that type as well as it uses functions from other files. Then:

1. Is there any way for one to have two types at the same time?
2. If not, how else could you solve this? It can not? Can't call a function from another file that uses functions from other files at the same time?

I'll appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way for one to have two types at the same time?

No

> If not, how else could you solve this? It can not? Can't call a function from another file that uses functions from other files at the same time?

The dirty hack would be to explicitly create the global variable

```html
<button onclick="foo()">Click me</button>

<script type="module">

function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}

window.foo = foo;

</script>
```

The modern approach would be to use the recommended method (since the late 1990s) and use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` attributes.

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<script type="module">

function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', foo);

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Quentin here, can we please remove the dirty hack. I wouldn't feel comfortable with anyone using this approach in 2021. Wouldn't also recommend it as a solution.